# ERROR Failed to load the "MercadoPago_Core/js/view/method-renderer/custom-method" component

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, magento2.3.4

I've been trying to install MercadoPago payment method, but system can't find js files?

Installing version 3.3.5 (current) from https://packagist.org/packages/mercadopago/magento2-plugin

Console errors display: `[ERROR] Failed to load the "MercadoPago_Core/js/view/method-renderer/custom-method" component.` for each mercadopago module activated.

I installed the latest package, run `setup:upgrade` and `setup:di:compile` but still nothing

Comment: Do you have the github link of this extension?

Comment: Yes, https://packagist.org/packages/mercadopago/magento2-plugin

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the problem, 3 days with such a thing, i don't believe =). Mate it was  blocked by the adblocker in the browser.
Hope this helps.

=).

Comment: Thank you very much! Save my life of hours debugging

Answer (score 1):

*I discovered the problem, 3 days with such a thing, i don't believe =). Mate it was blocked by the adblocker in the browser. Hope this helps.

=).*

This works!!

Answer (score 0):

1. What magento mode do you use?
2. Is the module enabled? `php/bin magento module:status`
3. Js compnent belongs to a "frontend" layer and should be compiled with `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` (in case that you are in production mode)
4. f you are in developer mode and module is enabled then remove data from `<dir>/pub/static/*` and flush web client cache
5. If none of this works check if the file really exists

Comment: Didn't work. Module is enabled, I'm in dev mode.
I think the file it's trying to reach is: `vendor/mercadopago/magento2-plugin/src/MercadoPago/Core/view/frontend/web/js/view/method-renderer/custom-method.js`.